# Import RSA public/private key from a string Crypto++

Tags: c++, rsa, crypto++

I would like to import a RSA key directly from a string variable, to use it with Crypto++library.

The code would look like this:
It is an example of what I want to do,not a working code.

```
std::string publickey_str =
    "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"
    "gm6mZA1NTZQJVUk9AGDb6NRngzRlRAgXBTWAispwlqsuHFoCrv02xPm1uxkLyfUq"
    "LoA4/EQJ25okjmGkrjgak+XmQIPKmAg94gWAtvRIrLZNmCj/aPeuikmCPXkKtg2b"
    "pdB6xzHY0ftGu0l6Vb8zttg7Wfo1kJowjoqCRwo9ex/IKwPXxE3UsugshcZOGdqT"
    "6E3B/Vw+JoerL/LfeOU2OYcSFEXsWqjzkrGzEVuKzRnve5RlXyY0gShP33f+hDnC"
    "F+Uu2tFfFgxRkdQPk7AKm4MCAwEAAQ=="
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
publicKey.load(publickey_str);
```

In the Crypto++ wiki, I only find how to import/export keys from/to files (.der, .pem). Do you know how can i do the same thing with a string ?

Edit: i apologize,i forgot to tell that i shortened the RSA public key for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I only find how to import/export keys from/to files (.der, .pem). Do you know how can i do the same thing with a string ?

In Crypto++, you can swap one source for any other source. You can change the `FileSource` for a `NetworkSource`, `StringSource`, `ArraySource`, etc.

The same applies to filters too. `HexEncoder`, `Base64Encoder`, `HexDecoder`, `Base64Decoder` and all interchangeable filters. It is not limited to encoders, and you can swap-in an encryption filter, signing filter or verification filter too. They can be swapped in and out because they all implement the `BufferedTransformation` interface.

And the same applies to sinks as well. You can change the `FileSink` for a `NetworkSink`, `StringSink`, `ArraySink`, etc.

---

The key you are showing is a PEM encoded key. To encode and decode in PEM, you need the [PEM Pack](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PEM_Pack). It's not part of the library proper so it's likely missing from your copy of the library. Rather, the PEM Pack is an add-on maintained by the community and you have to download and build it.

To use the PEM Pack, you need to rebuild the library from sources. To set things up:

```
$ cd cryptopp
$ wget https://www.cryptopp.com/w/images/5/5a/Pem-pack.zip
--2017-08-05 16:30:26--  https://www.cryptopp.com/w/images/5/5a/Pem-pack.zip
Resolving www.cryptopp.com (www.cryptopp.com)... 144.217.231.241
Connecting to www.cryptopp.com (www.cryptopp.com)|144.217.231.241|:443...
...
2017-08-05 16:30:26 (862 KB/s) - ‘Pem-pack.zip’ saved [20769/20769]

$ unzip -aoq Pem-pack.zip
$ ls pem*
pem-com.cpp  pem-create-keys.sh  pem-rd.cpp    pem-verify-keys.sh
pem-com.h    pem.h               pem-test.cxx  pem-wr.cpp
```

Then, make as usual:

```
$ make distclean
...

$ make -j 9
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c cryptlib.cpp
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c cpu.cpp
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c integer.cpp
...
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c pem-com.cpp
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c pem-rd.cpp
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c pem-wr.cpp
...
ar r libcryptopp.a cryptlib.o cpu.o integer.o 3way.o ... zdeflate.o zinflate.o zlib.o
```

Note: <strike>I need to fix the `auto_ptr` warnings. I'll get to it later today.</strike> This has been fixed. A new version of the [PEM Pack](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/PEM_Pack) is available from the wiki.

Now, you have PEM support:

```
$ nm libcryptopp.a | grep PEM | grep ' T ' | c++filt
00000000000000a0 T CryptoPP::PEM_WriteLine(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, CryptoPP::SecBlock<unsigned char, CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup<unsigned char, false> > const&)
00000000000000f0 T CryptoPP::PEM_WriteLine(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
0000000000000140 T CryptoPP::PEM_Base64Decode(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&)
00000000000004e0 T CryptoPP::PEM_Base64Encode(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&)
...
```

---

Here's the code.

```cxx
$ cat pem-test.cxx
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "integer.h"
#include "rsa.h"
#include "pem.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const std::string publickey_str =
        "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
        "gm6mZA1NTZQJVUk9AGDb6NRngzRlRAgXBTWAispwlqsuHFoCrv02xPm1uxkLyfUq\n"
        "LoA4/EQJ25okjmGkrjgak+XmQIPKmAg94gWAtvRIrLZNmCj/aPeuikmCPXkKtg2b\n"
        "pdB6xzHY0ftGu0l6Vb8zttg7Wfo1kJowjoqCRwo9ex/IKwPXxE3UsugshcZOGdqT\n"
        "6E3B/Vw+JoerL/LfeOU2OYcSFEXsWqjzkrGzEVuKzRnve5RlXyY0gShP33f+hDnC\n"
        "F+Uu2tFfFgxRkdQPk7AKm4MCAwEAAQ==\n"
        "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

    RSA::PublicKey publicKey;

    try
    {
        StringSource source(publickey_str, true);
        PEM_Load(source, publicKey);
    }
    catch(const Exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    const Integer& e = publicKey.GetPublicExponent();
    std:: cout << e << std::endl;

    const Integer& n = publicKey.GetModulus();
    std:: cout << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the result:

```
$ ./test.exe
BER decode error
```

It looks like your public key is bad. I'm not going to waste time on it because it is not clear to me if it is a real key, or it's a random junk you made up.

---

Regarding this:

> ```
> $ unzip -aoq Pem-pack.zip
> $ ls pem*
> pem-com.cpp  pem-create-keys.sh  pem-rd.cpp    pem-verify-keys.sh
> pem-com.h    pem.h               pem-test.cxx  pem-wr.cpp
> ```

I use the scripts for testing. You can delete them if you want. You can also delete `pem-test.cxx` if you want. It is not needed either.

```
 $ rm pem-*.sh pem-test.cxx
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I am loading a string into PublicKey

```
//Create Cryptopp StringSource From Std::string
std::string PublicKeyString = "<Your key as std::string value>";
CryptoPP::StringSource PKeyStringSource(PublicKeyString, true);
CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
publicKey.Load(PKeyStringSource);
```

Have a look at entire function for elaborate usage. Here I pass the keys as std::string in the function to verify signatures. `RSA::PublicKey` is created from `std::string` passed to function

```
bool Signature::VerifySignature(const std::string &PublicKeyString,
    const std::string &data,
    const std::string &SignatureStr)
{
    CryptoPP::StringSource PKeyStringSource(PublicKeyString, true);
    CryptoPP::StringSource SignStringSource(SignatureStr, true);

    CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
    publicKey.Load(PKeyStringSource);

    // verify message
    bool result = false;

    m_verifier.AccessPublicKey().Load(SignStringSource);

    CryptoPP::StringSource ss2(SignatureStr + data, true,
        new CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter(m_verifier,
            new CryptoPP::ArraySink((CryptoPP::byte*)&result,
                sizeof(result))));

    return result;
}
```